# Is it possible to add a random generated ID to an Automation Import

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a department providing me with a very basic CSV file that includes 3 fields, email address, first name, and last name. I'm using an Automation to pull that data in via FTP to a data extension daily.

Right now I'm using the "Overwrite" feature to prevent any errors from potential duplicates. Is there a way to add a 4th field to auto generate a unique ID?

I've accomplished this before using the GUID() function but only with using AMPScript with an email send.

I don't know how to do this using the Automation feature.

The department can't provide a unique ID on their end. This is something that needs to be accomplished during/after the import.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This would be something that you would need to add a SQL query and second DE to handle.

Basically you would:

1. Import as normal to your existing DE
2. Run a SQL Query adding a field being filled with `newid()` function
3. Have the results target your second DE that has the 'id' field in it.

So for the SQL, you would want something like:

```sql
SELECT EmailAddress,
FirstName,
LastName,
newid() as ID
FROM [myDE]
```

Which would target your second DE (you can choose overwrite, add or update action depending on your needs.

The second DE would be:

```
ID  |  EmailAddress  |  FirstName  |  LastName
```

Where you can set ID as pkey if you want to utilize that as the identifier.

This will add in a unique ID to your new records.